# How to close cerr

Tags: c++, posix

Yes, I can't. It seems weird ostream has no close, since istream can detect end of file.

Here's my situation: I am capturing all the output on Posix fd2, in this process, and its children, by creating a pipe and dup2'ing the pipe output end onto fd2. A thread then reads the read end of the pipe using an associated C stream (and happens to write each line with a timestamp to the original fd2 via another associated C stream).

When all the children are dead, I write a closing message to cerr, then I need to close it so the thread echoing it to the original error file will close the pipe and terminate.

The thread is not detecting eof(), even though I am closing both stderr and fd2.

I have duplicated my main program using a simple one, and using C streams instead of C++ iostreams, and everything works just fine by fclosing stderr (there are no child processes in that simplified test though).

Edit: hmm .. do I need to close the original pipe fd after dup2'ing it onto channel 2? I didn't do that, so the underlying pipe still has an open fd attached. Aha .. that's the answer!

Comment: I guess you send `^D` to end the stdio stream on linux and `^Z` on windows

Comment: Not all `ostream` are file based (e.g. `std::ostringstream`) so it shouldn't seem weird that you don't have a file like interface on an `ostream`.

Comment: You're right, but then we have weirdness that cerr can't be closed even though it is redirected to something close-able. However, I am closing the underlying C stream and file descriptor, and the read of the other end of the pipe is using an fdopen'ed C stream, and I know that they do get a close because I checked a simpler case.

Comment: When you `dup2` the pipe, did you `close` the original fd?

Comment: +1 @ Charles Bailey. No i didn't. I change the program to do so, and now it works fine. Now please repost your comment as an answer so I can tick it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you duplicate a file descriptor with `dup2` the original descriptor remains a valid reference to the underlying file. The file won't be closed and the associated resources freed until all file descriptors associated with a particular file are closed (with `close`).

If you are using `dup2` to copy a file descriptor to a well known number (such as 2 for `stderr`), you usually want to call `close` on the original file descriptor immediately after a successful `dup2`.

Answer (score 1):

The streams used for the standard C++ streams are the same as those controlled by the corresponding stdio files. That is, if you `fclose(stderr)` you also close the stream used for `std::cerr`. ... and since you seem to play with the various `dup()` functions you can also `close(2)` to close this stream.

Comment: Please read the post. I close both stderr and 2. It doesn't help.

Comment: When you `fclose(stderr)` or `close(2)` then the file descriptor is clearly closed. You might want to check if either of these fails but for a `popen()`ed file I'd consider this to be unlikely. To make sure that the closing message is sent you might need to flush the stream but `std::cerr` is generally set up to flush automatically after all output (using `std::unitbuf`). That is, your problem is unlikely to be the closing of the stream but rather the reading end.

Comment: Reading the question it seems unclear about what you are doing with the file descriptor. Is the thread you are expecting to terminate actually writing to this stream? If so, it won't detect that the stream is actually closed unless there is actually something attempted to be written to the stream.

Comment: @Deitmar: no, it's just reading the input end of the pipe, the output end of which is dup2'ed onto channel 2, so it captures all the error output from the program and all the child processes. The program is actually a process manager for testing 0MQ examples, which requires running multiple processes (clients, servers, etc).

Comment: Are you saying you are reading from a file descriptor which is written to by the child processes and the current program? You said you closed the stream in all of the children. Did you also close the file descriptor in the parent? As long as there is one program which keeps the file descriptor open it won't be recognized as closed (after all, it isn't). Also, if your children terminate they would close the descriptor automatically.

Comment: I found the problem, actually discovered it myself at the same time Charles Bailey was writing his comment. I neglected to close the file descriptor which was the write end of the pipe after dup2()ing it onto channel 2. So there was an open file descriptor which prevented the reading thread from seeing a close. It's all working now. Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0):

The best is to put a wrapper around your resource and then have the destructor close it when it goes out of scope. The the presention from Bjarne Stoustup

Comment: I don't need a lesson in C++, I need to figure out how to close a cerr/stderr/2 file which has been redirected to a pipe, so the read end can see an eof.